# trial and error do while statement in iOS

Tags: objective-c, do-while

I am new to iOS programming/objective c, I am trying to do an iterative trial and error calculation and I am stuck.  Ordinarily this code would have worked in excel VBA so I'm not sure how to overcome this issue in obj C:

```
- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {

    static float friction=2; 

    static float difference;


    float Re = [pipe_id.text floatValue] * [fluid_velocity.text floatValue] / [kin_viscosity.text floatValue];

ReynoldsNo.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%6.2f", Re]; 


do{

     float Colebrook1 = 1/powf(friction,0.5);

     float Colebrook2 = -2*log10f([RelativeRoughness.text floatValue]/(3.7*[pipe_id.text floatValue]) + 2.51/(Re*powf(friction,0.5))); 

     float difference = fabsf((Colebrook1-Colebrook2)*1000);                           

     friction = friction - 0.000001;


     FrictionFactor.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%6.2f", friction]; 

     Cole1.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%6.2f", Colebrook1];

     Cole2.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%6.2f", Colebrook2];         

    }while (difference > 0.000001);


}
```

So when I compile this, the value for friction stays at 2.  My loop isn't working, so the whole trial and error thing has fallen apart.  I need some help to see how this should be written in objective C.  Thanks for you help, ALM.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of block scope. Your inner `difference` shadows the outer, so you may want to avoid re-declaring it by simply removing the `float`.

Also, as a convention tip, leave the capitalized identifiers for classes.

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem:

```
float difference = fabsf((Colebrook1-Colebrook2)*1000);
```

You already declare the variable difference outside the loop; there is no need to declare it again inside the loop.

You probably want to say:

```
difference = fabsf((Colebrook1-Colebrook2)*1000);
```

Also, are you sure that your outer declaration needs to be `static`? That means its value persists between calls to the method. It's valid code, but unusual to see.

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen, that has helped.  At first I had ended up with a you are using an undeclared variable so I had tried declaring the variable outside the loop afterwards:
static float friction=2; 

I had used the static because I thought the variable would not be seen inside the loop.